# Identify the music genre

Tags: identify-this-genre

These songs are classifies as alternative/indie/rock or punk. But I feel there probably is a more specific genre.

I would describe it as having rather monotonous instrumental background, close to instrumental post rock (but faster and more punk-ish), it gives more importance to the vocal which is fast, more spoken that sung, just one voice and with abstract lyrics.

These are example songs:

- [Beautiful blue sky - Ought](https://open.spotify.com/track/2lp3ycHVNMK2xZ5GFMwEtX?si=__wfun1ATmyWeRyhEelEkA)
- [The leanover - Life without buildings](https://open.spotify.com/track/6cIgll9WthMHPFVy5ne9lC?si=ZjrTqzpFQKiKgGVE4A6Pog)
- [0:30 Gleiches Ambiente - Die Goldenen Zitronen](https://youtu.be/s-ULvJeqDdU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most specific common genre I found was **Spoken word post-punk**

Other artist I found searching for this genre were:

- From Monument To Masses
- Listener
- Slint
- Moss Icon
- ef
- Hotel Books

Answer (score 4):

Beautiful blue sky - Ought - Post Punk

The leanover - Life without buildings - Indie Rock with post punk influences

0:30 Gleiches Ambiente - Die Goldenen Zitronen - feels like Avant Garde but I'm not really sure

Comment: I rather was hoping to identify a common, more specific genre

Comment: Or not more specific, but common